# Magento different table name for admin grid

Tags: magento

I've build an extension with a table named after the extension.
Now I want to change the tablename and add '_items' behind it.
I changed the name in all de classes where I could find the name but to no result.
Im surely missing something but not sure what. Any help would be appreciated as where to define the table name

Comment: Have you checked at your modules `config.xml` under `config/models/yourmodulename_resource/entities/yourentityhandlename/table` ?

Comment: I actually have 2 tables so made 2 entities


<entities>
                    <customersatisfaction>
                        <table>customersatisfaction_mailqueue</table>
                    </customersatisfaction>
                </entities>
                <entities>
                    <customersatisfaction_questionnaire>
                        <table>customersatisfaction_questionnaire</table>
                    </customersatisfaction_questionnaire>
                </entities>

where the second is my table

Comment: so the table name can be only changed there.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, I think I've found what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the config.xml you can change what's inside the  tags to whatever table name you want it to point to. Just don't change the entity name (which is  and  in your case). You should not change anything in any of the classes. That's the beauty of the Magento architecture your classes do not depend on the table schema (ie table names).

Comment: So I didn't have to mess around in all the classes? hm should have known that sooner :-) I think I can solve it now. thanks for the help